# How to interpolate 2D array from a coarser resolution to finer resolution

Tags: numpy, scipy, netcdf, python-xarray

Suppose that I have an emission data with shape `(21600,43200)`,
which corresponds to the `lat` and `lon`,i.e,

```
lat = np.arange(21600)*(-0.008333333)+90
lon = np.arange(43200)*0.00833333-180
```

And I also have a scaling factor with shape of `(720,1440,7)`,which corresponds to `lat` , `lon`, `day of week`, and

```
lat = np.arange(720)*0.25-90 
lon = np.arange(1440)*0.25-180
```

For now, I want to apply the factor to the emission data and I think I need to interpolate the factor on `(720,1440)` to `(21600,43200)`. After that I can multiply the interpolated factor with the emission data to get the new emission output.

But I have a difficulty on the interpolation method.
Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) should solve your problem... as long as you can fit everything in memory (if you can't, you could compute the interpolation by pieces).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a complete example of the kind of interpolation you're trying to do. For example purposes I used `emission` data with shape `(10, 20)` and `scale` data with shape `(5, 10)`. It uses `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline`, which is the recommended method for interpolating on regular grids:

```
import scipy.interpolate as sci

def latlon(res):
    return (np.arange(res)*(180/res) - 90,
            np.arange(2*res)*(360/(2*res)) - 180)

lat_fine,lon_fine = latlon(10)
emission = np.ones(10*20).reshape(10,20)

lat_coarse,lon_coarse = latlon(5)
scale = np.linspace(0, .5, num=5).reshape(-1, 1) + np.linspace(0, .5, num=10)

f = sci.RectBivariateSpline(lat_coarse, lon_coarse, scale)
scale_interp = f(lat_em, lon_em)

with np.printoptions(precision=1, suppress=True, linewidth=9999):
    print('original emission data:\n%s\n' % emission)
    print('original scale data:\n%s\n' % scale)
    print('interpolated scale data:\n%s\n' % scale_interp)
    print('scaled emission data:\n%s\n' % (emission*scale_interp))
```

which outputs:

```
original emission data:
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

original scale data:
[[0.  0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.5]
 [0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6]
 [0.2 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.8]
 [0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.9]
 [0.5 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 1. ]]

interpolated scale data:
[[0.  0.  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5]
 [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6]
 [0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6]
 [0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7]
 [0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8]
 [0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8]
 [0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9]
 [0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9]
 [0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 1.  1.  1. ]
 [0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 1.  1.  1. ]]

scaled emission data:
[[0.  0.  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5]
 [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6]
 [0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6]
 [0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7]
 [0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8]
 [0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8]
 [0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9]
 [0.4 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9]
 [0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 1.  1.  1. ]
 [0.5 0.5 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 1.  1.  1. ]]
```

#### Notes

- The interpolation methods in `scipy.interpolate` expect both x and y to be strictly increasing, so you'll have to make sure that your `emission` data is arranged in a grid such that:

  ```
  lat = np.arange(21600)*0.008333333 - 90
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  lat = np.arange(21600)*(-0.008333333) + 90
  ```

  like you have above. You can flip your `emission` data like so:

  ```
  emission = emission[::-1, :]
  ```

Comment: probably, `lat_em, lon_em` should be replaced with `lat_fine, lon_fine` in your code example.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for nearest neighbor or linear interpolation, you can use xarray's native [`da.interp`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.interp.html) method:

```
scaling_interped = scaling_factor.interp(
    lon=emissions.lon,
    lat=emissions.lat,
    method='nearest')  # or 'linear'
```

note that this will dramatically increase the size of the array. Assuming these are 64-bit floats, the result will be approximately `(21600*43200*7)*8/(1024**3)` or `48.7 GB`. You could cut the in-memory size by a factor of 7 by chunking the array by day of week and doing the computing [out of core with dask](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.6.0/dask.html).

If you want to use an interpolation scheme other than nearest or linear, use the method [suggested by tel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398852/3888719).